# Cannot Log Back into Magento admin 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, extensions, error

Today I tried installing an extension called simitracking to track my store using my mobile phone. After I copied all the files included into my home/public_html/ as instructed, I tried logging back into magento admin and nothing happened. After inputting my user and password it just showed blank on the screen with this address:

"http://www.something.com/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/3a996847750ef2d43c9dbca5e1bb0a62/"

I heard this could be a cookie problem and I tried following instructions here but also to no avail:
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075539/cant-login-to-magento-admin"

and here:

"http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how_to_fix_login_for_admin_on_local_install"

I tried everything including clearing cookies and using different browsers and it still didn't work. I've also searched through the internet for at least 6 hours yet I'm still lost. There is no problem loading the front end but I cannot access the back end admin pages.

I look forward to anyone's help. Thank you.

Comment: You problem can't be reproduced by us, therefore it is hard to help you. Read https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store to help yourself!

Comment: You my have compilations turned on.  To disable them, go into your `includes` folder, and rename your `config.php` to something else, flush your caches, and try again.

Comment: @RyanStreet, thank you. That works and I can access my dashboard again!

To all admins, I apologize for going off-topic. I wish there was an easier way to contact you guys for help because the forum isn't working anymore and I've been searching around like a headless chicken trying to find answers. Thank you everyone here for being so patient with me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you clear the cache and session files on the server?

Go to [magento]/var/cache and delete all files. Same with [magento]/var/session. Once done you should be let in.

Comment: I followed what you said and deleted all files inside [magento]/var/cache and [magento]/var/session, and now it said this when I tried going into www.something.com/admin:
"There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 1390600045587"

Comment: You deleted too much. :-) You also need to view that error. Go to [magento]/var/errors and rename the local.xml.sample file to local.xml Now you will have your error presented on screen.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no /var/errors. :( However, I found var/report if that helps!

Comment: It is actually just 'errors' in the folder root.

Comment: Found it and it says:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magestore_Simisalestrackingapi_Model_Bestsellers_Order' not found in /home/magento/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 31056

Comment: Did you comment out that module then?

Comment: Deleting `var/session` is never an appropiate solution. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94589/keeping-customers-logged-in-after-deleting-var-session

Comment: If the site is falling over due to a fatal error and some things are mysteriously held in cache due to a clumsy upgrade, plus you cannot log in, then 'never' is a bit extreme. Really with the above the module was not tested before being deployed and the world of pain should not have happened.